# Saving Realm Object subclass in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I'm introducing Realm into my swift project. I have a User class that I was saving an instance of into NSUserDefaults to keep track of the 1 logged in user.

After making User a subclass of Object, I get the following error when trying to unarchive (archiving seems to work OK):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (RLMStandalone_User) for key (root); the class may be defined in
>   source code or a library that is not linked'

I have Realm installed as a Cocoapod, this are the relevant methods in the User clas

```
static var currentUser: User? {
    get {
        if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(UserDefaultKeys.kUserData) as? NSData,
            let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? User {
            return user
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    set {
        if let user = newValue {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(user)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.kUserData)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(UserDefaultKeys.kUserData)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

 convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    guard let firstName = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as? String,
    let lastName = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as? String,
    let email = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("email") as? String,
    let icloud = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("icloudUserID") as? String,
    let userType = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("userType") as? String
    else {
        return nil
    }

    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.email = email
    self.profilePic = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("profilePic") as? String
    self.icloudUserID = icloud
    self.userType = userType
    self.coverPhoto = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("coverPhoto") as? String
    self.facebookID = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("facebookID") as? String
    self.placeID = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("placeID") as? String
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(self.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    coder.encodeObject(self.lastName, forKey: "lastName")

    coder.encodeObject(self.icloudUserID, forKey: "icloudUserID")
    coder.encodeObject(self.userType, forKey: "userType")
    coder.encodeObject(email, forKey: "email")

    if let coverPhotoUrl = self.coverPhotoUrl {
        coder.encodeObject(coverPhotoUrl, forKey: "coverPhoto")
    }

    if let profilePicUrl = self.profilePicUrl {
        coder.encodeObject(profilePicUrl, forKey: "profilePic")
    }

    if let fbID = self.facebookID {
        coder.encodeObject(fbID, forKey: "facebookID")
    }

    if let placeID = self.placeID {
        coder.encodeObject(placeID, forKey: "placeID")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to store a Realm `Object` in `NSUserDefaults` as (As you saw in that error message) they cannot be serialized or deserialized by the `NSCoding` protocol.

Instead, it might be better to add a primary key property to your `User` object (So you can use it to query that exact object from Realm), and store the primary key itself in `NSUserDefaults` instead.

Or better yet, instead of relying on `NSUSerDefaults`, it might be better to simply have a boolean property, `isCurrent` in your model, and using that to work out which user is the current one.

Comment: Thanks, I did see it as redundant immediately but wanted to try it to leave this unchanged. In my context current user is the logged in user, so I don't think the flag will work, unless I just don't sync that property to the backend and keep it realm only. I do like the primary key in nsuserdefaults so I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your NSUserDefaults and your Realm data separate. They are two different methods of persistent data storage. If you've converted something to a Realm Object, you no longer need to (or should) try and put that into NSUserDefaults.